# stop systemctl using graphical sudo prompt

Tags: linux, sudo, systemd

My question is how could I configure systemd(?) to stop opening this annoying pop-up whenever I forget to type sudo. Just give me a text-based sudo prompt or show an error, so I can correct the mistake quickly.

This is Arch Linux, latest (systemd 238.133).

[image]

Comment: Check out this answer and method and see if this helps you come up with a solution that'll work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/692701/allowing-user-to-run-systemctl-systemd-services-without-password... one more than may give you clue if applicable as well: https://serverfault.com/questions/841306/authentication-is-required-to-manage-system-services-or-units

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a 'sudo' prompt, this is a 'polkit' prompt. One way to avoid it – global to *all* software, not just systemctl – is to write a polkit rule that immediately denies the action (or immediately allows it).

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (subject.user !== "root") {
        if (/^org\.freedesktop\.systemd1\./.test(action.id)) {
            return polkit.Result.NO;
        }
    }
});
```

(The `subject.user` test could be omitted, as actions invoked by root bypass polkit checks entirely.)

polkit rules are stored in `/etc/polkit/rules.d/*.rules`, generally named like `80-custom.rules` (processed in ascending order). For more information see [polkit(8)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/master/polkit.8.html).

---

(That said, if your sudo configuration is passwordless, then there's no practical security difference between using 'sudo' vs making polkit immediately allow the action. And vice versa, if your sudo *requires* a password... then why not just enter it into the polkit dialog? It's the same password.)

Comment: it works a treat, thanks for the answer. I'm just a bit uneasy about the fact that system privileges are apparently managed by javascript, of all things??

Comment: @MightyPork: It's not the best choice, but there's nothing inherently insecure about it anyway, and Mozilla's SpiderMonkey is probably as battle-tested as they come.

Answer (score 3):

There is an option `--no-ask-password`. Make an alias:

```
alias systemctl='systemctl --no-ask-password'
```

(tested in Bash, Kubuntu).

Comment: this doesn't work for me, the pop-up opens anyway (systemd 238.133)

Comment: Centos7: fails with "Interactive authentication required." message...

Comment: @tonioc This means my answer works. The OP's requirement was "…or show an error".

Answer (score 1):

Do not use sudo for systemctl, **ever**; if you **are** permitted to do the maintenance, set up polkit properly.

**Rationale**: `sudo` makes the program you run effectively by the requested user (usually: `root`). Including all the toolkits linked. Any bug in the program, libraries or ...sudo configuration makes you vulnerable. In case of `systemd`, the `systemctl` binary is only a **controller** (in general). It **does not** require root priviledges (for most use cases), as it doesn't perform priviledged operation by itself, but asks `init`. Using the actual `root` account (either directly or via `sudo`) is all-or-nothing atomic (bomb) solution, while the **only** thing, that is required, is to **authorize** (**not: authenticate**) **against `systemd`**. Since `systemd` understands `polkit` for **authorization**, using **authenticated `root`** is just too much permissions granted.

Consider a bug in `systemctl`, that allows to invoke arbitrary command directly (not via `systemd`). When `root` permissions are given by `sudo`, one can run any command with EUID=0. With `systemctl` running as unpriviledged user, one can only run such command with the account he gained access before. This is a simple consequence of some basic security rules:

- use only the set of permissions, that are required (not the full set == `root`),
- grant these permissions only to the code, that requires it (authorize in `systemd` without granting permissions to `systemctl`).

As for the being the sole user of a machine - if you work using non-priviledged account, not the `root` one, I assume you want to restrict programs you run from gaining superfluous permissions. Giving them to `systemctl` only because the `root` account is `authorized` to command `systemd` is such superfluous permission.

Moreover, with `polkit` you can have different access criteria for different actions (start/stop/reload/whatever) and different services. You can put exact commands in `sudoers`, but polkit solution is aware of the specific parts of such commands.

**Concluding**: don't use `sudo` if any less-priviledged method is available. `sudo` is all-or-nothing last-resort solution.

If you want the password prompt to be shown in text, not graphical, just <del>unset DISPLAY, e.g.:</del> unbind your terminal from the graphical session, that runs authentication agent.

Comment: Your first "suggestion" is entirely unsubstantiated. The second will be ineffective, because the graphical password prompt is not spawned by systemctl.

Comment: I'm the sole user of my laptop. Why should I even want to learn complicated polkit when plain old `sudo` does its job just fine here? I'd like to keep things simple. Systemd itself is complex enough, why to make it worse with polkit? For now I find your statement sadistic. Tell me one sane reason, I may change my mind.

Comment: If you don't know, why you shouldn't use sudo, you might as well just work using root account. No password prompt would bother you anymore. After all, you're the sole user of your laptop.

Comment: This is a question & answer site. If the OP doesn't know, your job is to explain it why.

Comment: Kamil isn't OP, and comments are not for answering subsequent questions.

Comment: Comments are not for answering, OK, but I'd rather have my question answered in your *answer*, which lacks reasoning. I assumed there is something *I don't know*, I gave you a chance to *teach me* before I vote the answer down. You failed. I read your comment as "if you don't know already, you don't deserve to learn from me". Quite arrogant. Still I'm giving you feedback so you can do something about my downvote. I don't use `NOPASSWD` so I don't understand why you mention "no password prompt". Is it because `sudo` can authorize any command for few minutes after I type my password once?

Comment: I was referring to your *I'm the sole user*. Using sudo **in general** is bad, and it doesn't do **THIS** job *just fine* - it does way too much than required for this specific purpose. Rationale for this doubt - answered above.

Comment: Now we're talking. +1.